# Is it a bad idea to use [Char] instead of String in Haskell function type declaration

Tags: haskell, sublimetext2, hlint

I have just started learning Haskell using "Learn you a Haskell for Great Good". 
I am currently reading "Types and Typeclasses" chapter, so my knowledge is pretty .. non-existent.
I am using Sublime Text 2 with SublimeHaskell package which builds/checks file on every save.

The problem: I'm trying to make function type declaration like this:

```
funcName :: [Char] -> [Char]
```

I'm getting this warning:

> Warning: Use String
>     Found:
>       [Char] -> [Char]
>     Why not:
>       String -> String
>
> Build FAILED

Can you explain to me why is it a bad idea to use Char array instead of String or give me a link to an explanation of possible repercussions etc. I've googled and found nothing.

P.S. I'm a C# developer, I understand the difference between char array and strings in c-like languages.

Comment: `[Char]` and `String` are the same thing. I don't know what SublimeHaskell does, but I'm guessing it's running some sort of lint-type checking on your code.

Comment: From now on, I'm going to use only notepad++ and ghci in order to reduce the noise while learning. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, you should use `Text` for serious coding when you become more proficient with Haskell.  It offers better space efficiency and performance.  Lazy lists are better control structures than data structures.

Comment: Rule in the ST2 plugin may be an artifact of this: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html#id607949

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Somewhere in the base library you will find this definition:

```
type String = [Char]
```

which says that `String` and `[Char]` are exactly the same thing.  Which of the two you choose is a documentation choice.  I often define type aliases like this:

```
type Domain = ByteString
type UserName = Text
```

It's a good idea to use types for documentation.

Also as an important side note, `[Char]` is not the type for character arrays, but character lists.  Since there are also actual array types, the distinction is important!

Comment: Thanks for additional tips

Comment: In addition using type aliases sometimes makes it easier to refactor the code later on. When refactoring functions with a type alias you only have to refactor the implementation while the type signature stays the same.

Answer (score 7):

`String` is nothing more than a type alias for `[Char]`, so there is no practical between the two - it's simply a matter of readability.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be running HLint on your code automatically, and treating any HLint warnings as fatal errors. As [the HLint author says](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/how-i-use-hlint.html) "Do not blindly apply the output of HLint". `String` and `[Char]` are exactly the same, as everyone says, it's a question of which looks nicer. I would tend to use `String` if I'm operating on contiguous lists of characters I want to treat as a block (most of the time), and explicitly use `[Char]` when the characters don't make sense combined in a run (far rarer). HLint divides all hints into error (fix) and warning (think), so perhaps it might be best only to build fail on error hints.